# JOOQ - How to get the tbl_name.col_name of a TableField?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

How to get the table + column qualifier name from the [**TableField**](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/class-use/TableField.html).

I have tried the following methods

```
USER.ID.toString(); // "db.user.id"
USER.ID.getName();  // "id"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've noticed, the `TableField.toString()` method renders the fully qualified column. You have two options:

#### Do it yourself:

```
String sql = USER.getName() + "." + USER.ID.getName();
```

#### Use a `Configuration` that is configured to omit the schema name:

```
Settings settings = new Settings();
settings.setRenderSchema(false);                    // Omit schema rendering
settings.setRenderNameStyle(RenderNameStyle.AS_IS); // Omit escaping names
DSLContext = DSL.using(SQLDialect.MYSQL, settings);
String sql = ctx.render(USER.ID);
```